# Turning an XML into a select

Tags: sql, xml

I'm trying to turn this XML string into a select

I have @Schedule XML = '<days><day enabled="0">0</day><day enabled="1">1</day><day enabled="1">2</day><day enabled="1">3</day><day enabled="1">4</day><day enabled="1">5</day><day enabled="0">6</day></days>'

What I'm trying to see at the end is..

DayNumber          DayEnabled
   0                          0
1                          1
2                          1
3                          1
4                          1
5                          1
6                          0

I've tried a few ways, so far nothing is working right.. I am handling this as an XML data type, I'd prefer not to use a function as this will just be in a stored procedure..

Update: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly..
I have a stored procedure, XML is one of the parameters passed to it, I need to send it to a table to be inserted, so I'm trying to do the following..

INSERT INTO tblDays (DayNumber, DayEnabled)
SELECT @XMLParsedOrTempTableWithResults

I just can't figure out how to parsed the parameter

Comment: What database? What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myXML as XML = '<days><day enabled="0">0</day><day enabled="1">1</day><day      enabled="1">2</day><day enabled="1">3</day><day enabled="1">4</day><day enabled="1">5</day><day enabled="0">6</day></days>'

DECLARE @XMLDataTable table
(
DayNumber int
,DayEnabled int
)

INSERT INTO @XMLDataTable
SELECT d.value('text()[1]','int') AS [DayNumber]
,d.value('(@enabled)[1]','int') AS [DayEnabled]
FROM @myXML.nodes('/days/*') ds(d)

SELECT * FROM @XMLDataTable
```

Refer:

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10279/xquery-labs-a-collection-of-xquery-sample-scripts.aspx

Comment: EXACTLY what I needed, phew... been pulling my hair trying to figure this out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The XMLTABLE function is how most XML-enabled DBMSes shred an XML document into a relational result set.

This example uses DB2's syntax for XMLTABLE and an input parameter passed into a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO tblDays (DayNumber, DayEnabled)
SELECT X.* FROM 
    XMLTABLE ('$d/days/day' PASSING XMLPARSE( DOCUMENT SPinputParm ) as "d" 
        COLUMNS 
           dayNumber  INTEGER  PATH '.',
           dayEnabled SMALLINT PATH '@enabled'
    ) AS X
;
```

Comment: I've adjusted the code to reference an input parameter . If your DBMS supports XMLTABLE, it doesn't make much difference if the input document is coming from a parameter or an XML column in a relational table or expression.